# Evenly distribute text within a DIV

Tags: html, css, alignment

Can't seem to find anything else covering this. I have the text aligned to the centre but I would like for there to be even spacing on all sides of the text but so the text still fits within the DIV.

So Instead of `|Page1Page2Page3Page4|` You'd get something like `|  Page1  Page2  Page3  Page4  |` Including equal spacing on the ends of the text too.

```css
.navigation-container {
width: 60%;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.nav {
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
font-size: 2vw;
text-align: center;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: #000000;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;
line-height: 1em;
object-fit: contain;
text-decoration: none;
}

.nav:hover {
color: #096e67;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navigation-container">
<p class="nav">Page1</p>
<p class="nav">Page2</p>
<p class="nav">Page3</p>
<p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
```

It is to be used as a navigation bar, the other 40% of the page will be used to contain the logo. I'll eventually have these stack for mobile or add a drop-down.

I would use `hspace` but it has been depleted and the amount of space must scale based on device as the text shouldn't leave or overflow the DIV. Because they're already centred I don't know how I'd pad the sides to fit with the device based on the text size.

Super confused, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`justify-content: space-evenly;`

OR

`justify-content: space-around;`

OR

`justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.navigation-container {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  //justify-content: space-evenly; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.space-evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.space-around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.space-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  color: #000000;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  line-height: 1em;
  object-fit: contain;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav:hover {
  color: #096e67;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="navigation-container space-evenly">
  <p class="nav">Page1</p>
  <p class="nav">Page2</p>
  <p class="nav">Page3</p>
  <p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-around">
  <p class="nav">Page1</p>
  <p class="nav">Page2</p>
  <p class="nav">Page3</p>
  <p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
<div class="navigation-container space-between">
  <p class="nav">Page1</p>
  <p class="nav">Page2</p>
  <p class="nav">Page3</p>
  <p class="nav">Page4</p>
</div>
```